# How to update the value of an existing config key in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, config

Take the example...

```
<add key="IDs" value="001;789;567"/>
```

How do you update (append to) the value only of an existing key in the App.config programatically?

```
<add key="IDs" value="001;789;567;444"/>
```

My code currently has the below to add new keys, but I don't know how to **update** keys.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(appKey, appKeyValue);

// Save the changes in App.config file.
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it via the Settings key or indexer.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("YourConfigFilePath");
config.AppSettings.Settings["IDS"].Value = "001;789;567;444";  // Update the value (You could also use your appKey variable rather than the string literal.

config.Save();
```

As an additional note it may be easier to import the `System.Configuration` namespace rather than using the `System.Configuration` alias each time.

Comment: Wouldn´t be easier utilize   Var = My.Settings.IDS + newvalue      My.Settings.IDS = Var     My.Settings.Save   ?

Comment: Thanks @Darren Davies, this was exactly what I needed, works great.